# Ошибка Python TypeError: 'Matrix' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Не могу понять в чем ошибка.

**line 51, in __str__
    self.matrix[i][i-1] = 0
TypeError: 'Matrix' object is not subscriptable**

*Еще мне подсказали, что можно обратиться вот так m1.matrix, тогда тоже будет работать*

```
import numpy as np


class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.sum1, self.sum2 = 0, 0

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([''.join(['%d\t' % i for i in row]) for row in self.matrix])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.matrix)

    def sum_diagonal(self,):
        n = len(self.matrix)
        for i in range(n):
            self.sum1 += self.matrix[i][i]
        for i in range(n):
            self.sum2 += self.matrix[i][n-i-1]
        return self.sum1 + self.sum2

    def zero(self):
        n = self.matrix.__len__()
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if i > j:
                    self.matrix[i][j] = 0
        return '\n'.join([''.join(['%d\t' % i for i in row]) for row in self.matrix])

    def __add__(self, other):
        A = np.array(self.matrix)
        B = np.array(other.matrix)
        C = A + B
        return C

    def __sub__(self, other):
        A = np.array(self.matrix)
        B = np.array(other.matrix)
        C = A - B
        return C


class Zero(Matrix):
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        Matrix.__init__(self, matrix)
        self.n = len(self.matrix)

    def __str__(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            self.matrix[i][i-1] = 0
        return '\n'.join([''.join(['%d\t' % i for i in row]) for row in self.matrix])


z = Zero(Matrix([[5, 3, 1, 1, 1], [-1, 2, 2, 1, 1], [4, 1, -1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 6, 1, 1], [4, 1, -1, 1, 1]]))
print(z)
```

Comment: Какая версия? У меня ошибка по другому сформулирована.

Comment: версия python 3.8

Comment: Ну ведь и правда вы не реализовали у класса Matrix доступ к элементам по индексу, оттого он и не работает.

Comment: вы не могли бы, пожалуйста, подсказать как это сделать или дать пример, потому что я как никак не могу понять как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

достаточно определить метод

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self.matrix[index]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!